# How to allow use sign ' with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

At the momemnt I'm using this regular expression to validate address

```
(!/^[A-Za-z]/i.test(street))
```

When I use address like this - **Esterwergen** - it works.

But when I added the sign before the title - **'Esterwergen** - it shows my error.

Ho I can modify my RegEx and allow to use this sign before the name?

Comment: Surely you made a typo and meant `.test(street)` ?

Comment: Try `(!/^[A-Za-z']/i.test(street))`

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, sorry I changed it! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow an optional leading `'`, you'd change your regexp from

```
/^[A-Za-z]/
```

to

```
/^'?[A-Za-z]/
```

where the `?` means "zero or one times".

If you want to allow the `'` anywhere in your string,

```
/^['A-Za-z]/
```

would do the trick.

In addition, be sure that you realize that you're only checking the first character of the string as it is.

Right now you will allow `Ester9ui4y6ewigkdlLNDSKJ#€=# :::`.

To constrain that, you'll need the `+` quantifier and the `$` (end-of-string) anchor.

```
/^[A-Za-z]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Lets see what is your RegExp targeting:**

- `/^[A-Za-z]/i`
- `^`: Asserts position at start of the string.
- `[]`: Match a single character depending on what's inside.
- `A-Z`: Match uppercase letters from `A` to `Z`.
- `a-z`: Match lowercase letters from `a` to `z`.
- `i`: Case-insensitive.

**Consider this:**

- Using `[A-Za-z]` along with `i` flag is redundant. Use `/^[a-z]/i` or `/^[A-z]/` instead.
- Using `[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF]` for example extends matching to latin characters using UNICODE syntax. See full UNICODE reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).
- Use `/^['a-z]+/i` to allow `'` anywhere in the string.
- Use `/^'?[a-z]+/i` to allow `'` only at the beginning of the string. `?` means '1 time or 0 times'.

To play around with RegExp you can use tools like [this](https://regex101.com).